# How do you convert a call to a class/function to a string in Python?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and self taught. I have used Stack Exchange to find answers to many of my questions without ever needing to ask (it is a great community), but I cannot seem to find the answer to this anywhere. I apologize if this is a duplicate.

I am trying to assign a method to a variable, but I want to save it to a text file for access later. I am using open() to access the text file and eval() to change it from a string when loading the information. I just cannot figure out how to do the opposite.

```
from random import randint

class Example (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
        self.lucky_number = ""

    def create_person(self):
        self.name = input("What is your name?")
        self.lucky_number = randint(1,10)
        save_person = [self.name, self.lucky_number]
        with open("example.txt", "w") as f:
            for i in save_person:
                f.write(i + '\n')

    def load_person(self):
        with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
            person_list = f.readlines()
        if len(person_list) <= 1:
            create_person()
        else:
            self.name = person_list[0].strip('\n')
            self.lucky_number = eval(person_list[1].strip('\n'))

person = Example()
person.load_person()
```

I want to keep the randint(1,10) part because I want to reuse the function, but I may change the value to something else later depending on user selection (such as changing self.lucky_number = randint(1,10) to self.lucky_number = randint(1,30)).

I know I can just change it to self.lucky_number = randint(1,var) and then save the value of var instead, but it made me wonder if the way I'm trying is possible.

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I am using Python 3.5.

Edit: For clarification I am looking to store the actual function, i.e. randint(1,10), in the text file, not the value of the function.

EDIT 2: I am going to close this as answered because I found a way to do what I needed, but it is not a direct way.

Comment: I think you might want to look in to "serialization of objects in python." This can allow you to store objects and load them in later. https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/pickle.html

Comment: Thank you. I just reviewed the link you posted and that is something I am very interested in doing. In the meantime I am bouncing between Python 3.5 on my Pi3 and Pythonista on my phone, and it is currently easier to just check the txt file to make sure each step writes correctly and I can change values quickly to test new additions. The next step was figuring out how to make it unreadable for humans and you thankfully pointed me in the right direction. Thank you!  :) In the meantime it is easier to see the randint(1,10) to change it than just 10. Is that possible?

Comment: So would you want to store the function call (`randint`) *including its arguments* (`1` and `10`)? At this point I don't quite understand the need for storing it anymore, because it's neither user input (like the name) nor a randomly determined value (because you wouldn't be storing the value anymore, but the function name and it's arguments).

Comment: At that point, you'd basically just be saving to a file what you already write yourself in source code. So you could easily factor out that function to say `def generate_lucky_number(): return randint(1, 10)`, and put that function into its own `.py` module and import it. But I get the feeling that's not what you're after.

Comment: @Lukas Graf you are correct that I am looking for the actual function, not the value. I edited my question to clarify this. Sorry for the confusion. The actual script I'm using this for spans several scripts and a lot of data, so for simplicity I rewrote it to my example. It is the function I need stored (actually a method from a different class) and this method will change as the user makes selections to different classes. For example, depending on the user, class a may have randint(1,10) but class b may have randint(1,30). The method is reused, so the value isn't important, but the method is

Comment: But the possible choices of methods (using 10, 30, etc...) are predefined (by you)?

Comment: The methods are constructed in different classes. For example, if this was a racing game the Toyota acceleration method is in the Toyota class and the Mustang acceleration method is in the Mustang class. I just need the method to store depending on whether the user picks Toyota or Mustang. Its possible to just store the 10 from randint(1,10) as its own variable, but the txt file is enormous. Keeping track of all the numbers will get difficult, which is why I wanted the whole method (easier to locate and modify).

Comment: @LukasGraf you're correct. I am already importing the modules I created, but its running the function and storing the value when I save, when I want it to just store the actual function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find a way to accomplish what I was looking for, but it is a roundabout way. I changed the call to the function into a string, then created a new class variable that calls the variable with the function string. The other class variable meant to run the function now has eval() around it and calls the new class variable I created. I save the new class variable instead.

```
from random import randint

# Now a string instead of a function call
prog = "randint(1,10)"

class Example (object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = ""
"""Added self.temp to grab the string from outer 
variable and will change self.temp to get the desired
functions as strings"""
        self.temp = prog
"""self.lucky_number grabs new class variable and
eval() turns it into callable function"""
        self.lucky_number = eval(self.temp)

    def create_person(self):
        self.name = input("What is your name?")
        self.temp = prog
        self.lucky_number = eval(self.temp)
""" Saves new class variable now and stores actual 
function, eg randint(1,10)"""
        save_person = [self.name, self.temp]
        with open("example.txt", "w") as f:
            for i in save_person:
                f.write(str(i) + '\n')

    def load_person(self):
        with open("example.txt", 'r') as f:
            person_list = f.readlines()
        if len(person_list) <= 1:
            self.create_person()
        else:
            self.name = person_list[0].strip('\n')
            self.temp = person_list[1].strip('\n')

person = Example()
person.load_person()
```

Its roundabout, but gets the job done. I can change self.temp to whatever variable (formatted properly) I need and the code will work. If anyone can think of a direct way please let me know.